# how to pass value to ajax response and receive in success function

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, response

i have array which i want to pass in ajax response

```
$val = [10 , 20 , 30];
```

here is i want to pass $val somtehing like this but i dont know the method

```
return response()->json(['success'=> true, 'message' => 'Success' , 'val' ]);
```

this `$val` i dont know how i can pass and receive it in console
here i want to receive

```
success: function (data) {

             if(data.success == true){
                 
                     toastr.success(data.message);
                     console.log(data.val);
             }
```

can someone help me? to receive value in console?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not sending the `val` property in your response. So just like you have `success` and `message` in your json response, include a `val` property too and pass the `$val` variable.

Comment: i have tried 'Seller Report Saved Successfully.' , '$val'  but it doesnot work in console.log(data.val);

Comment: 'val' is the property name. A property needs both a name and a value, maybe you shouldn't call them both `val` to avoid confusion. So in order to give it the value of the variable, you need to do:

`return response()->json(['success' => true, 'message' => 'Success' , 'val' => $val]);`

Comment: oh thanx it is worked for me thnax for your help and contribution

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
return response()->json(['success' => true, 'message' => 'Success' , 'val' => $val]);
```